# Erro Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Ao gravar um modulo no joomla 3.0 apareceu-me este erro:

```
1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' SQL=SELECT
i.*, v.name AS author FROM stw3q_k2_items as i LEFT JOIN
stw3q_k2_categories AS c ON c.id = i.catid
LEFT JOIN stw3q_users AS v ON v.id = i.created_by
WHERE i.trash = 0 AND c.trash = 0 ORDER BY i.created DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

E a partir deste erro não abre mais a pagina inicial do website, como ultrapassar este erro?

Comment: Qual versão do mysql vc usa? rode essa consulta `show engines` deve mostrar que innoDB está habilitado.

Comment: A versão é 5.5.45-cll

Comment: E o retorno da consulta?

Comment: como faço essa consulta?

Comment: Abre o mysql ou o phpmyAdmin e rode ela.

Comment: O servidor mysql está offline